# Jenkins changelog is showing all the changes done to the repository instead of last successful build

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, changelog

My Jenkins job is configured with gerrit and I'm using git as the version control tool. Whenever the job triggers the changelog is showing all the changes done to the repository instead of pulling only from last successful build. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are probably doing a fresh checkout everytime **or** you are constantly changing the SCM location that you checkout from (through a variable in SCM configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if option *Shallow Clone* is disabled in Code Repository->Additinal Behaviours->Advanced Clone behaviours in the job definition.

This option is known to cause issues in building change log while integrating with some external tools (GitLab, GitHub).